# How to get the certifcate from Key vaults using power shell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I need help on this scenario. we have a cert in azure key vault which needs to be download to a windows VM for our .net application to run on iis. I am able to upload the cert to Azure keyvault with out issues. I am running a azure devops powershell tasks inline powershell script.

1. it will connect to azure using conenct-azaccount with appropriate login creds.`enter code here`
2. we run invoke-azvmssruncommand and specific the script path and variable which needs to be passed as parameters.
3. in the PowerShell script we have script to get the cert from azure keyvualt once its connected to azure vm

below is the error
error: an error occurred while sending request. need your thoughts on it.
Invoke-AzVmssVMRunCommand -VMScaleSetName dev-CTUS   -ResourceGroupName RG -InstanceId $instanceid -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript'-ScriptPath  "path"\downloadcertfromkeyvault.ps1" -Parameter @{"vaultname"= "keyvault name";"certname"="app-DEV";"password"= "jdksjkdjalksd";"said"="";"sapuserid"; password"="password";"devSubscriptionId"="ZXXXXXXXXXX"} -Debug

this is the command which i used in azure devops powershell inline script .

```
inside powershell script 

$SecurePassword = "$sapassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $said, $SecurePassword
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant "XXXXXXXXXXXX-a68c-41e5-XXXXXXXX"

Write-log "setting subscription to retrive certs"
Set-AzContext $devSubscriptionId

$password = "$password"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$password" -AsPlainText -Force

$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultname -Name $certname
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultname -Name $cert.Name 
$pfxpath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret.SecretValueText)
$x509Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
$type = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pfx
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export($type, $password)

# Write to a file
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$pfxpath\$certname.pfx", $pfxFileByte)

$certificate= Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My`   `

Write-Log $certificate
```

Comment: `error: an error occurred while sending request` - This is not really useful. Please try to run the PowerShell script with `-Debug` parameter and that should give more information about the operation. Once you have that information, please edit your question and include that. Also, please edit your question and include your PowerShell script.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** put your code in comments. Instead edit your question and include it there.

Comment: how do i add debug logs ? any help i have saved it in txt file

Comment: You can (in fact, should) add them here only just like you added the code. Please do strip out/mask any confidential information (subscription id, tenant id, access tokens etc.) from the logs before adding them here.

Comment: i cannot add the debug logs it  says too long even if i strip or mask
"message": "Connect-AzAccount : An error occurred while sending the request.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindo
ws\\1.1.8\\Downloads\\s\ncript10.ps1:52 char:1\n+ Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant \" ...\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], HttpRequest \n   Exception
\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmA \n

Comment: any help from any one ?

Comment: Could you please try to run the script directly in your VM?